# Reading Ground/Open signal wire combonations to power specific LED's - Can it be done?

Tags: programming, input, signal-processing

This might be a super easy question to answer. I ordered an Arduino Uno anyways for the sole purpose to understand this. Would not mind getting a jump on things before it's here.

I would like to setup the Arduino Uno to be used as a gear indicator for GM transmissions (specifically right now the GM 4l60e). Below is how it currently tells the computer/cluster what gear it's in.

This uses a range switch. Basically it's a combination of 4 wires that are grounded (low) in a specific order, the computer reads it, and displays what gear the transmission is in. There are 4 signal wires - Signal A,B,C, and P. Below is how the range switch signals it:

```
Park    - A=low,  B=open, C=open, P=low
Reverse - A=low,  B=low,  C=open, P=open
Neutral - A=open, B=low,  C=open, P=low
OverDrv - A=open, B=low,  C=low,  P=open
Drive 3 - A=low,  B=low,  C=low,  P=low
Drive 2 - A=low,  B=open, C=low,  P=open
Drive 1 - A=open, B=open, C=low,  P=low
```

I am wondering what would be the best way to go about this? The Arduino would be powered on by ignition. Display would be an LED (9-12V) output from the Arduino to each gear on a floor mount shifter. Total of 7 LEDs.

Hopefully this is easy to understand what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the output to be - is it 7 single LEDs, so exactly one will be on at once? Or perhaps you're not asking about the output - just how to read the input..?

Comment: Yup, sorry about that.
7 single, different LED's representing a gear would be the output.
The main question being is it possible for the Arduino to intake 4 wires that could be ground or open at any instance and take that info and make an output to power an LED representing the combination (listed above).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Arduino is a 5V device, as such to drive the 9-12V LED you will need to use one or more transistors (depending on the LEDs type, number and connection, in series or in parallel).

Also, powering the Arduino from a 9-12V is not the best option: Arduino Uno has an onboard voltage regulator, but goes up to 9V maximum and, unless you go for the original one or a reputable manufacturer (Arduino is an open source project) I wouldn't go above 6V, because non-reputable manufacturers tend to use lower specs devices, like regulators which can get too hot when powered with high voltage: consider that the regulator will have to dissipate any excess energy into heat.

Said that, and knowing nothing more than what you said about the transmission you are describing, I assume the status `open` stands for *open collector*, meaning that it is not going to draw any current, so the following circuit is what you should use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5WPHv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diagram assumes you are using digital pins 5 to 8 of your Arduino in `INPUT` mode and the Arduino GND is at the same voltage level as the transmission: this might be a big assumption, depending on how you power your Arduino (not from a battery pack, to be clear).

When node `A` is in `open` state, the voltage on Arduino pin `5` will be 5V, or HIGH as Arduino reports it. When node `A` is in `low` state then the voltage on Arduino pin `5` will be 0V, or LOW in Arduino lingo.

Resistors from `R1` to `R4` are there to limit current drawn when the gearbox is in state `low`.

UPDATE: I'm assuming the gearbox shares the same ground and operates at 5V,a s the Arduino does. If that's not he case and the gearbox operates at an higher voltage or does not share the same ground, the circuit will not work and you risk damaging the Arduino and/or the gearbox.

You can find a simulation of the above circuit where you can play with the different pins [here](http://tinyurl.com/ycxrp4q9).

The same occurs for the other pins, so your code will have to scan the 4 pins for their state and update your display accordingly, like:

```
#define PIN_A 5
#define PIN_B 6
#define PIN_C 7
#define PIN_P 8

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN_A, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_B, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_C, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_P, INPUT);
}

#define PARK 0;
#define DRIVE_1 1;
#define DRIVE_2 2;
#define DRIVE_3 3;
#define OVER_DRIVE 4;
#define REVERSE 5;
#define NEUTRAL 99;
#define UNDEFINED 255;

unsigned int gear = UNDEFINED;
void loop() {
    bool A = digitalRead(PIN_A);
    bool B = digitalRead(PIN_B);
    bool C = digitalRead(PIN_C);
    bool P = digitalRead(PIN_P);

    if (!A && B && C && !P) {
      // Park - A=low, B=open, C=open, P=low
      gear = PARK;
    } else if (!A && !B && C && P) {
      // Reverse - A=low, B=low, C=open, P=open
      gear = REVERSE;
    } else if (A && !B && C && !P) {
      // Neutral - A=open, B=low, C=open, P=low
      gear = NEUTRAL;
    } else if (A && !B && !C && P) {
      // OverDrv - A=open, B=low, C=low, P=open
      gear = OVER_DRIVE;
    } else if (!A && !B && !C && !P) {
      // Drive 3 - A=low, B=low, C=low, P=low
      gear = DRIVE_3;
    } else if (!A && B && !C && P) {
      // Drive 2 - A=low, B=open, C=low, P=open
      gear = DRIVE_2;
    } else if (A && B && !C && !P) {
      // Drive 1 - A=open, B=open, C=low, P=low
      gear = DRIVE_1;
    } else {
      // none of the above
      gear = UNDEFINED;
    }
    // update your display here
}
```

Please note the above code is NOT the most efficient, but I believe it's easier to read and understand than a version using bitwise operations to identify the possible combinations.

Comment: Awesome, this really helps! Power source can be changed. The ECU in the vehicle that this is going to be tested in has plenty of 5v references. So if that would be better I can do that. But this really helps. Kudos! I will jump right on it when it gets here and see what we get, thanks again!

Comment: Please consider my update and also consider the fact the gearbox and the Arduino must have a common ground for this circuit to work.

Comment: Also consider there are more robust solutions than what I've here described and I would NOT advice to use the circuit I've diagrammed above unless you have double checked the gearbox and it's current draw capabilities. Personally I would opto isolate all interactions diagrammed above between the gearbox and the Arduino: voltage spikes are not uncommon in a vehicle electronics.

Comment: It is. It is totally separate. I am just using it to show gear indication. The ECU on the vehicle gets all it's info based on the floor shift. It does not use the range switch on the transmission. The range switch was not even being used. I just thought that I would like to have the indicator lights based on what gear the transmission is actually in vs what the sifter "thinks" it's in the way it is currently lit up as. This whole setup is completely separate from the actual vehicle operation. Just for me to see. It's a hotrod setup.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on what you have commented here: if both the gearbox and the Arduino operates at 5V then the whole circuit gets simplified and the shared ground will greatly simplify your circuit. All you need are pullup resistors to bring the voltage level HIGH when the gearbox outputs are `open`.

Comment: @Roberto Lo Giacco - Could he use INPUT_PULLUP instead of INPUT in pinMode() to eliminate the need for external resistors?

Comment: *I wouldn't go above 6V* - actually 7.3V would be about the minimum. There is circuitry to switch between the power jack input and the USB input. It is based on a comparator which compares double 3.3V (there is a voltage divider) from the 3.3V regulator to Vin, after the protection diode. So 6V is too low for it to switch to using the power jack. You would need 6.6V plus the voltage drop over the diode, so really 7.3V would be about the minimum. Possibly with no USB input it would take whatever it got, but still ...

Comment: If you have a 5V supply that is regulated and filtered you could put that direct into the 5V line of the Uno (and not into the power jack).

Comment: @VE7JRO actually no, those resistors act as pullups but they are also limiting the current sink by the gearbox open collector output when it is turned low: without the external resistors it is possible the gearbox creates a short to ground when turned low. Does it make sense?

Comment: @NickGammon that's totally right

Comment: @Roberto Lo Giacco - The transmission switch is ONLY providing a ground, so the Arduino Uno internal pull up resistor is providing the excess current protection when the input pin is grounded through the switch. The OP is not using the switch with the PCM connected to 12V as shown in this diagram: http://www.truckforum.org/threads/transmission-problems-4l60e.36202/. Please have a look at the "Park/Neutral Position (PNP) Switch" part of the circuit.

Comment: @VE7JRO the _ground only_ connection is what I described as _open collector_, so I was aware of that. When internal pullup resistor is enabled you are actually connecting the Arduino pin to VCC via a 20k resistor so the final circuit would look like http://tinyurl.com/yd6k8xea

So you are right, good catch!